# I iterate a loop within another loop, based on the same array, what's the best way to ignore duplicates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save all combinations of an array. So for
[a, b, c] I want to save
[ab, ac, ba, bc, ca, cb]

I currently use this method:

```
for (coordinate in coordinates){
    for (coordinate2 in coordinates){
        if (coordinate != coordinate2){
            newposts.push([fbposts[fbpost].id, coordinates[coordinate], coordinates[coordinate2]]);
        }
    }
}
```

but it generates a bunch of duplicates. What's the smoothest way to solve this?

Comment: If `coordinates` is an array, don't use `for in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a modified [bubble sort](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/bubbleSort.htm) algorithm:

```
var result = [],
arr = 'abc'.split('');

// begin the bubble sort loop
for(var i=0,l=arr.length;i<l-1;i++)
    for(var j=i+1;j<l;j++)
        {
            result.push(arr[i]+arr[j]);
            result.push(arr[j]+arr[i]);
        }
console.log(result); //["ab", "ba", "ac", "ca", "bc", "cb"]
```

By looping over the array in this way, you do not even need to check if the result is a duplicate, because it doesn't generate any.
Btw, don't use the `for..in` synthax for looping over arrays because it may have unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Add a check before adding to your new array either by custom function or perhaps

```
array.indexOf(...)
```

Custom function similar to how jQuery does it:

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So as you are building your new array of permutations/combinations (been 13+ years since my last stats class), perform a quick check and don't add if true, otherwise add.  I believe if you perform an array merge it'll do similar so same performance.

Comment: This link may be useful for you too: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_indexof.htm

Comment: if you have jquery use $.inArray(value, array)

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of the fact that you can define a property only once and have something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var arr = ["a","b","c"];
    var permutations ={};
    $.each(arr, function(index1, val1) 
    {
        $.each(arr, function(index2, val2) 
        {
            permutations[val1+val2] = 0;
        });      

    });
    for(var prop in permutations)
    {
        //in prop you will have your elements: aa,ab...

    }        

});​
```

*permutations* would play the *role* of a dictionary in this case

The logic of generating the combinations is sub optimal as the run time is n square - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n) questions for algorithms of generating combinations of k elements out of an n elements array